# Magento 2 Fishpig wordpress

Tags: magento2, third-party-module, blog

I'm new to magento, I need help to develop following features.

1. Next previous post buttons to post view page
2. Show popular post in the widget area
3. A slider using recent post featured images.

Could find find much help resources for magento 2 fishpig :(

Comment: I have found the getNextPost() and getPreviousPost() method inside the Post.php model.now need to find a way to use those methods.

Comment: Ok,  Marius. http://magento.stackexchange.com/users/146/marius. thanks

Comment: 1.Next previous post buttons to post view page

Comment: 1.Next previous post buttons to post view page - I did this using Post.php model.

Comment: 2.Show popular post in the widget area- I have edited the recent post widget, I know this is not the correct way but its timely helpful . I have used category to filter posts. because hit counter faced  cache problem eg. <?php $posts = $this->getPosts();$posts->addCategoryIdFilter(2);  ?>

Comment: This is my slider script I used postlist class block view phtml script is -  
if ($posts = $this->getPosts()):
    $posts->addIsViewableFilter();
    $posts->setPageSize(6);
endif;